# Excel Funcion Horizontal Subtotal Funcyion to Hidden Colmns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a report with horizontal table that contains hidden columns. I use `sum` function to sum all the data, but I want a tool that will show me gaps and will sum without the hidden columns. Is there any simple way to do this?

Comment: did you try the SUBTOTAL() function?

Comment: @ScottCraner yes, it is not working horizontal.

Comment: sorry, then you will need vba, or transpose your table.

Comment: I guess I got confused with your initial use of rows, instead of the current Columns

Comment: @ScottCraner, Yes i had a mistake writing rows.